# validate GETUTCDATE() from stored procedure in gherkin feature file

Tags: c#, automation, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Stored Procedure:

```
UPDATE clients SET enabled=0,editDate=GETUTCDATE() WHERE clientid=@clientid
```

feature file

```
Given a clean database
    Given the following Clients table
    | clientid | name    | url          | enabled | lastChangedBy | createDate | editDate   |
    | 1        | Client1 | https://test | true    | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
    When the "ClientDelete" stored procedure is run with the following parameters
    | name     | value |
    | clientid | 1     |
    Then the following is returned
    | clientid | name    | url          | enabled | lastChangedBy | createDate | editDate   |
    | 1        | Client1 | https://test | false   | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
```

C# code

```
public void ThenTheFollowingIsReturned(Table table)
{
    var results = _context.Get<DataTable>("Results");
    Assert.AreEqual(table.Rows.Count, results.Rows.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var expectedRow = table.Rows[i];
        var actualRow = results.Rows[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < table.Header.Count; j++)
        {
            var name = table.Header.ElementAt(j);
            var type = actualRow[name].GetType();
            object expectedValue = expectedRow[name];
            if (expectedValue.ToString().IsNullText())
                expectedValue = null;
            else if (type != typeof(DBNull))
                expectedValue =
             TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromInvariantString(expectedRow[name]);
            var actualValue = Convert.IsDBNull(actualRow[name]) ? null : actualRow[name];
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, name);
        }
    }
}
```

fails where the stored procedure with `GETUTCDATE()` returns current date and time and scenario contains date only(GETUTCDATE will return current time everytime it runs the test so not good to change date or time in gherkin file to just pass the test). can we put current date and time or similar to get in gherkin/specflow? if not what are the options.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var name = table.Header.ElementAt(j);
var type = actualRow[name].GetType();
object expectedValue = (name).Contains("Date") ? DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : expectedRow[name];
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and i tried this but still same error